# Codeigniter select query is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data from database using CI. But my code is not working. 
Showing error :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: h
>
> Filename: confrence/load_Confrence_passes.php

Here is my controller code:

```
public function load_Confrence_passes()
    {
        //load the model
        $this->load->model('confrence_model');

        //load the method of model
        $data['h']=$this->confrence_model->confrencepasses();

        $this->load->view('mheader');
        $this->load->view('confrence/load_Confrence_passes');
        $this->load->view('mfooter');
    }
```

And here is my Model code:

```
public function confrencepasses()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('confrence_cat','Confrence passes');
        $query = $this->db->get('confrence');
        return $query;
    }
```

And here is my view code:

```
<div class="row">
            <?php
            foreach($h->result() as $row)
            {
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12 semminar-pass reg">
                <div class="col-sm-8 border">
                    <span class="col-sm-12 training-title"><?php echo $row->confrence_title ?></span>
                    <span class="col-sm-12 training-extra-info"><?php echo $row->confrence_description ?></span>
                    <div class="training-bar col-sm-9"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <span class="col-sm-12 training-price">
                    <strong><?php echo $row->confrence_price ?> $</strong>, Taxes included</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 last-block">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 btn-oa" data-relation="5">
                        <span class="border-left border"></span>
                        <span class="border-right border"></span>
                        <i class="jbt-icon icon-oa"></i>
                        Learning Objectives
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a id="btn-atsc-5" class="btn-add-to-shopping-cart " href="javascript:void(0)"
                           onclick="addTrainingToShoppingCart(5);">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                            <span class="text">Add to cart</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

This is the first time I am working on CI.

Comment: you forgot to pass `$data['h']` to views.

Comment: @kamoteulalo if he not pass `$data['h']` array to views, then how he will use the `$h` variable?

Comment: @Ayyappaamara then that will be another question. what your saying won't answer the current question. because the code can't even go through the controller to view.

Comment: I agree with @Ayyappaamara ,the `$data` is not passed to the view from controller so it shows error.

Comment: yup my bad. i just found it. Sorry @Ayyappaamara , thanks anyway! It's my bad to look only at the controller.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: @tanmaybhawsar if your problem solve then give as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass `$data` array to views then you can hold the array in views.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function load_Confrence_passes()
{
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('confrence_model');

    //load the method of model
    $data['h']=$this->confrence_model->confrencepasses()->result();

    $this->load->view('mheader');
    $this->load->view('confrence/load_Confrence_passes',$data);
    $this->load->view('mfooter');
}
```

In Views

```
<?php 
foreach($h as $row)
{
   echo $row->confrence_title;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is passed from the controller to the view.

Parse data like `$this->load->view('content', $data);`

public function load_Confrence_passes()
    {

```
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('confrence_model');

    //load the method of model
    $data['h']=$this->confrence_model->confrencepasses();
    $this->load->view('content', $data);
    $this->load->view('mheader');
    $this->load->view('confrence/load_Confrence_passes');
    $this->load->view('mfooter');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes in Controller

```
public function load_Confrence_passes()
{
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('confrence_model');

    //load the method of model
    $data['h']=$this->confrence_model->confrencepasses();

    $this->load->view('mheader', $data);
    $this->load->view('confrence/load_Confrence_passes');
    $this->load->view('mfooter');
}
```

Changes in Model

```
public function confrencepasses()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('confrence');
    $this->db->where('confrence_cat','Confrence passes');        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Changes in View

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach($h as $row)
        {
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 semminar-pass reg">
            <div class="col-sm-8 border">
                <span class="col-sm-12 training-title"><?php echo $row['confrence_title']; ?></span>
                <span class="col-sm-12 training-extra-info"><?php echo $row['confrence_description']; ?></span>
                <div class="training-bar col-sm-9"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <span class="col-sm-12 training-price">
                <strong><?php echo $row['confrence_price']; ?> $</strong>, Taxes included</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 last-block">
                <div class="col-sm-6 btn-oa" data-relation="5">
                    <span class="border-left border"></span>
                    <span class="border-right border"></span>
                    <i class="jbt-icon icon-oa"></i>
                    Learning Objectives
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a id="btn-atsc-5" class="btn-add-to-shopping-cart " href="javascript:void(0)"
                       onclick="addTrainingToShoppingCart(5);">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                        <span class="text">Add to cart</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

This may help you..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make this way and you'll have certain variable available in all views/partials:

```
public function load_Confrence_passes()
{
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('confrence_model');

    //load the method of model
    $data['h']=$this->confrence_model->confrencepasses();

    $this->load->vars($data);// https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars

    $this->load->view('mheader');
    $this->load->view('confrence/load_Confrence_passes');
    $this->load->view('mfooter');
}
```